# link_to_remove_association: undefined method `new_record?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I'm trying to build 2 nested forms with Cocoon which works fine. I have a Game model which has many Questions and a Question has many Answers.

## Models

```
# Game model
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, allow_destroy: true
end

# Question model
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :game
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
  validates :text, presence: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, allow_destroy: true
end


# Answer model
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
end
```

the link_to_add_association link works everywhere, the link_to_remove association link works fine in _question_fields partial view but I have

```
`"undefined method `new_record?' for nil:NilClass"`
```

error when I insert the link_to_remove_association in _answer_fields partial view. I'm sure that it's an error on my part but I can't retrieve where.

## error

[image]

## Views

### new.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: @game,  url: games_path, local: true ) do |form| %>

  <div class="form-group game">
    <%= form.label(':name', "Title") %>
    <%= form.text_field ':name', class: 'form-control form-control-sm' %>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper-questions"></div>

  <%= form.fields_for :questions do |question_form| %>
    <%= render 'games/partials/question_fields', f: question_form %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="row form-actions links">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <%= link_to_add_association 'Add a question',
          form,
          :questions,
          :partial => 'games/partials/question_fields',
          class: "btn btn-secondary",
          'data-association-insertion-node' => '.wrapper-questions'
      %>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm text-right">
      <%= form.submit 'Save', :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

### partials/_question_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="question-wrapper jumbotron nested-fields">
  <%= link_to_remove_association f, { class: 'btn btn-light' } do %>
    <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete the question
  <% end %>

  <p><strong>Question</strong></p>

  <div class="form-group">
    <strong><%= f.label(:text, 'Question:') %></strong>
    <%= f.text_field :text, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :questions do |answer_form| %>
    <%= render 'games/partials/answer_fields', f: answer_form %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="row">
    <div id="wrapper-answers"></div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <%= link_to_add_association 'Add an answer',
          f,
          :answers,
          :partial => 'games/partials/answer_fields',
          data: { 'association-insertion-method' => :prepend },
          class: "btn btn-secondary"
      %>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### partials/_answer_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="row nested-fields">
  <div class="col">
    <%= f.text_field :text, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <label class="btn btn-secondary form-control">
      <%= f.check_box :correct %>
    </label>
  </div>


  <!-- My error is here -->
  <%= link_to_remove_association 'remove answer', f %>
</div>
```

Does anybody have an idea what I'm doing wrong ?
Regards, 
Lilith

Comment: We need to see where you're defining link_to_remove_association to see whats causing the error

Comment: Just at the end of my question, in the partials/_answer_fields.html.erb, the last code inserted

Comment: ah I've just seen its a cocoon method

Comment: Yeah, its a cocoon method and I've copy/paste the line from cocoon documentation. The same link works in the question_fields partial view but I have the error when I put this link in the answer_fields partial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `partials/_question_fields.html.erb`

```
<%= f.fields_for :questions do |answer_form| %>
```

Should likely be :

```
<%= f.fields_for :answers do |answer_form| %>
```

Comment: A copy-paste problem :/